# function for multi char replacement in jsonnet

Tags: jsonnet

How can I replace multiple chars in a string?

My current strategy is to nest the `stdlib` functions:

**tst.jsonnet**:

```
local tst = '0-1.2';

{
  tst: std.strReplace(std.strReplace(tst, '.', '_'), '-', '_'),
}
```

output:

```
> ./jsonnet tst.jsonnet
{
   "tst": "0_1_2"
}
```

I would love to be able to use the function, something like:

```
std_name(tst, ['.', '-'], '_')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `jsonnet` [doesn't support regex](https://github.com/google/go-jsonnet/issues/409) (which would greatly help with this use-case), nevertheless you can write your own function implementing your `std_name()` (I named it `strReplaceMany()` in below code):

```
local tst = '0-1.2';

// Loop over fromArray (of strings), running std.stdReplace()
local strReplaceMany(str, fromArray, to) = std.foldl(
  function(retStr, from) std.strReplace(retStr, from, to),
  fromArray,
  str
);
{
  tst: strReplaceMany(tst, ['.', '-'], '_'),
}
```